Combining layer information from two different maps into another, separate map in R/terra
I am a bit new to geographic analyses, so apologies if I am not using 100% the correct terminology. I was hoping I could get some help on putting together different information layers on one map. I am using R and preferably the terra package.
In this specific instance, I have a shapefile of US EPA Level IV ecoregions that I have downloaded from here. This gives a map of the continental US and has layers which delineate ecoregions. I am then cropping to just the Pacific Northwest.
epa4.vect <- vect("level_4_ecoregions/us_eco_l4.shp") # Read the shapefile in as a vector
epa4.vect <- project(epa4.vect, "epsg:4326") # project in lon/lat, WGS84

pnw_extent <- ext(-126, -109, 32.5, 49.5) # set extent
epa4.vect.cropped <- raster::crop(epa4.vect, pnw_extent) # crop vector
# plot(epa4.vect.cropped)

epa4.rast.cropped <- rast(epa4.vect.cropped, nrows = 1500, ncols = 1000) # Convert to raster
epa4.rast.cropped <- rasterize(epa4.vect.cropped, epa4.rast.cropped, field = "US_L4CODE") # adding the layer for ecoregion data (the use of both rast() and rasterize() honestly confuses me but it seems to work?)
plot(epa4.rast.cropped) 

What I would like to do is get a separate map which includes Canada as well:
country_codes("North America")
us_canada <- gadm(country = c("Canada", "USA"), level = 1, resolution = 1)

And then somehow combine the raster I have with another dataset which includes biogeoclimatic (BEC) zones for British Columbia (obtainable from here). That way I would have an object that can show both ecoregions and BEC zones. The purpose would be to generate some models for data that I have and then add the predictions from the models to the raster so that I can show my predictions on a combined map.

Why to rasterize the vector in the first step? Seems the BEC zones are downloadable as vectors as well. Just plot them with terra::plot(1st_vector), terra::plot(2nd_vector, add = TRUE). To "zoom" to specific coordinates use ext paramter (or xlim, ylim) of plot, see ?terra::plot().

@GrzegorzSapijaszko You are probably right, I guess I just found myself working with raster files before so that's what I was going with. Supposing I kept it as a vector, how then would I combine these two sets of layers into one object?

Just rbind() them, see ?terra::c()

Wow, OK I did not expect it to be that simple, huh. Thanks!

As Grzegorz Sapijaszko mentioned in a comment, the solution is as simple as using rbind() on the vectors for each dataset. This generates a vector that simply has NA in the columns for US when showing BC locations and vice-versa.
